# Request video from a WinForm in a Web Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, webforms, camera

I was wondering if this is possible.  I have a Web Form in Visual Studio 2010 that gets an image from an IP camera using WebRequest, but is it possible to request from a Windows form?  Like if the IP camera feed is being played in the win form, then request from the win form instead of requesting from another website that has the ip camera.  I hope I have been clear enough in what I want.  Here is the code for getting the image from the IP camera that I have right now:

```
namespace ViewImage
{
public partial class getimage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The code that loads the single image and sends it back to the stream

        //Query the camera for a single image on the local network
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ip address");
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        //Stream the image to the response stream for use by the java app to refresh the image
        Stream stm = resp.GetResponseStream();
            System.Drawing.Image img = new Bitmap(stm);
        stm.Close();
        img.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    }
}
}
```

Now this works fine, but I don't want to call from the IP address of the camera every time someone visits the site.  They might as well just type in the IP address themselves.  I want to have the video feed being called from the IP address once in a win form and then have the webform call from that win form to get the image.  But I don't know how to do this or if this is even possible.

The reason I am doing this is my boss wants to have a site for other higher ups to view cameras that are set up around oilfields and use as little bandwidth as possible.  So the idea is to get the video feed once in a windows form app and have that running on our server.  Then have the web form call that win form for the images. I don't know if what I have is already kind of doing this already. I already have the windows form app that plays the live ip camera feed; I just don't know how to do a request for it.

Comment: One way is to use wcf. Winform will be your server and webform client.

Comment: Is that a third party software?  I don't know of it.

Comment: No. Its windows communication foundation. Its a part of .net. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx